# Micro-Typography with Luatex

Tags: spacing, luatex, typography, microtype, kerning

Since I wanted to use `Opentype` with Latex, I had to go with `Luatex` and consequently am now missing some features of `Microtype` (spacing, kerning). (I tried converting my openfonts but failed)

Here is an example text, and what I don't like about it:

Since I use a special font, a pdf is better than a picture:
http://de.scribd.com/doc/228281466/Minimal-Example

The interword spacing just does not look right, e.g. comparing line 2 and 3; specifically the space between "of visual obtrusion" in line 2 and the spaces between "or at the margins of" in line 3.

Any hints? Maybe using `luaotfload` could help?
Basically, I am looking for ways to enhance the appearance of my text and I am open to all suggestions and tips.

Examplecode:

```
\documentclass[oneside,paper=A4,DIV=9,smallheadings,12pt,]{scrbook}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont[
Ligatures=TeX,
Renderer=Basic,
Path=/Library/Fonts/,
Extension=.otf,
]{RotisSerifStd}
\newfontfamily\secfont{RotisSansSerifStd-ExtraBold}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\secfont} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.18}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Micro-typography with Tex}

        Micro-typography is the art of enhancing the appearance and readability of a
        document while exhibiting a minimum degree of visual obtrusion. It is concerned
        with what happens between or at the margins of characters, words or lines. Whereas
        the macro-typographical aspects of a document (i.e., its layout) are clearly visible
        even to the untrained eye, micro-typographical reﬁnements should ideally not even
        be recognisable. That is, you may think that a document looks beautiful, but you
        might not be able to tell exactly why: good micro-typographic practice tries to
        reduce all potential irritations that might disturb a reader.

        Some essential micro-typographical aspects are already taken care of by TEX out
        of the box – and in an outstanding manner – namely, hyphenation and justification,
        as well as kerning and ligatures. Other aspects are in the user’s scope of responsi-
        bilities, e.g., to specify the right amounts of spacing around punctuation characters,
        numbers, or quotation marks. On top of this, a number of long-standing micro-
        typographic techniques have been introduced to the TEX world relatively recently
        with pdfTEX, and have since also propagated to LuaTEX and   XTEX. These features
        make them the tool of choice not only for the creation of electronic documents
        but also of works of outstanding time-honoured typography: most prominently,
        character protrusion (also known as margin kerning) and font expansion. Quoting  ́
        Hàn Thê Thành, the author of pdfTEX, who writes in his thesis:
 \end{document}
```

For good reference the example text can be compared to the microtype documentation.

**Edit**:
Possible improvements:

- `\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=alltext,letterspace=-10]{microtype}`

Though this shifts the heading weirdly and turns off protrusion:

[image: Microtype with tracking and letterspace]

- `\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,stretch=80]{microtype}`

[image: Microtype with stretch=80]

Thoughts and opinions very welcome!

Here is a good example but with different font, line spacing and macro-typography:

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the interword space you have the key `WordSpace`. E.g., `WordSpace = {1,0,0}` ensures that the interword space has no shrinkability nor stretchability so all spaces are the same (this might not be desired, it's just an example, look at the documentation for more info).

Comment: You are loading fontspec and so you are already using luaotfload - look in the log-file and you will find it. It is certainly possible to implement the missing features in luatex - but someone has to do it.

Comment: could you add your versions of `luatex`, `luaotfload` and `microtype`?

Comment: `luatex` is beta-0.76.0-2013052718  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627), `luaotfload` is v2.4-3 and `microtype` is v2.5a

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it is only valid for standard `pdflatex`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but it didn't effect the interword spacing.